# What is best tool to generate source to source code other than Haxe?

Tags: sdk, shared-libraries, cross-platform, haxe, cross-language

I need to develop an sdk for an app and we have many clients written in many languages such as js, java, python, swift, CPP... etc. Do we have any language which we can use to write the SDK and it will translate it into other source languages?

I found **haxe** language which can do this. But I want to know if anybody has any other suggestions or anybody has a better idea to do it.

Comment: Other option would be to write a minimal code generator like PlayFab has it - they combine auto-generated functions with handwritten parts of implementation.